# Home Page plagiarism risks from a competitors

Tags: seo

What are SEO risks and what are the best courses of action via Google, when an industry competitor duplicates 95% of your home page content and passes it as their own. Especially when your own website has ranked for years etc and held this unique copy for years.

Further to this - what are the implications when another industry competitor replicates both your entire site design template and word for word content across your ENTIRE website?

Comment: Sounds more like a lawyer task like a SEO one.

Comment: Google detects duplicates and the master will always get preferred. If anything if they are coping you its a good thing, because they will never rank. Only the template style is not detected, text copying = bad seo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can log a take down notice with Google, either through their special [DMCA page](http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en-gb&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs&&rd=1) or through [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1&).

You should also lodge a complaint direct with the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](https://www.dmca.com/Protection/signup.aspx)